# Can't create new user: Error on All inbox permission sets are in use

Tags: permission-sets, inbox

While trying to create a new user, I get the error that 'All inbox permission sets are in use'
[image]

- We had the Inbox feature in the past, but we didn't go with it.
- It's disabled.
  [image]

Is that the issue?

I tried to delete the assignments with workbench (can't see how to do it other way), got these error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error,  you have to first remove permission set "Inbox without einstein Activity Capture'   from user.

remove permission set from user detail page.
if you are not able to do so run permissionsetassignment query  for user  in developer console or workbench  and delete records.

select assigneeid,permissionset.label from permissionsetassignment  where assigneeid = ''

Comment: thanks. apparently, the error was misleading, and the message I got. The error actually happened while trying to activate a frozen user. Removed the Permission set before activation, and it works.